# create a list of datetime objects using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, list, datetime, strptime

I have a list of strings.

```
date_str = ["2012-11-04 1:05:21", "2013-11-03 1:05:21", "2014-11-02 1:07:31"]
```

I want to read them as datetime objects. For one string, I do

```
datetime.strptime(date_str[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but I don't know how to create a list of datetime objects. 
If I use

```
datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: must be string, not list
```

I tried using a loop:

```
x = datetime.strptime(date_str[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
for i in range(1,len(date_str)):
    x.append(datetime.strptime(date_str[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

but I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Is there a way to create a list of datetime objects?

Answer (score 5):

`x` must be a list:

```
x = []
for i in range(len(date_str)):
    x.append(datetime.strptime(date_str[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

then, you can append all  your datetime objects. Or even more Pythonian:

```
x = [datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for s in date_str]
```

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl. I tried this before and when I print x, I get the following
    [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 4, 1, 5, 21), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 1, 5, 21), datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 2, 1, 7, 31)]
if I print x[1], it will give me the correct format. 
    2013-11-03 01:05:21

Comment: @AsiehHarati Yeah, if you print a list, it will use the `repr` method of its elements, and not the `str` which used when you print them directly. You can compare: `print repr(x[0]), str(x[0])`